# New Contact/ New Quote/New Lead options are not displaying in Salesforce Side panel(Salesforce for outlook)

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, outlook

New Contact/New Quote/New Lead options are not displaying in Salesforce sidepanel in outlook. New Task / New Event options are displaying.

Done:
1) Created a new publisher layout ,added New Contact/New Quote/New Lead options and assigned to my profile(Admin).

It would be great help if anyone knows what i am missing. :)